# How to divide an integer n <= 12 to an array of 12 elements so that I could divide this array to as equal as possbile periods

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to divide an integer N <= 12, which is a number of work days, to 12 months, so that if I divide 12 months into
periods of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 6 months, the number of days in these periods should be as equal as possible.

For example:

If N = 6, the array should look like this :

`1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0` or `0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`

N = 4

`1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0`

N = 3

`1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0`

N = 2

`1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0`

edit:

what I mean by "as equal as possible" is that when I divide this array into periods, the number of work days in these periods shouldn't differ by more than 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "as equal as possible": the length of the intervals should differ by no more that 1, or as many as possible are the same length, or something else?

Comment: Can `N` go beyond 12? what about prime number values like 5?

Comment: @Ankush 1 <= N <= 12, any number in this interval.

Comment: and what about N = 5? How will you divide this?

Comment: @Ankush just like 3 above, it seems

Comment: isn't N = 3 wrong? It should be 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT -- Improved for the general case, assumed you were only asking for 1,2,3,4,6 as in question!**

What you want is to modulate N by a given period. (My terminology is likely entirely wrong :D Should probably go read up on my high school physics again!)

Have some Ruby..

```
def spread_it(n)
  d = 12.0 / n
  (0..11).map do |index|
    (12.0 - (index % d) > 11.0) ? '1' : '0'
  end
end

(1..12).each do |n|
  puts "N=#{n} - #{spread_it n}"
end
```

Output is:

```
N=1 - ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
N=2 - ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
N=3 - ["1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0"]
N=4 - ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"]
N=5 - ["1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]
N=6 - ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0"]
N=7 - ["1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1"]
N=8 - ["1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1"]
N=9 - ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1"]
N=10 - ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
N=11 - ["1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
N=12 - ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
```

Better now? :)

Comment: @Kevin hey, could you please explain what d = 12.0 / n is ? And how does this (12.0 - (index % d) > 11.0) line work ?

Comment: @Kevin ? Could you please explain ? This is very important !

Comment: Hey! sure. d is the interval length, it's the average length of each chunk if you need n pieces.  `(12 - (index % d) > 11.0)` is specific arithmetic which assumes there are 12 months. Sorry, I wrote it really late at night but it should be simplified to `(index % d < 1) ? '1' : '0'` which is basically just checking to see if the index is a multiple (within limits, e.g. 3 % 2.4 = 0.6 which is basically 'close enough to being a multiple' for this purpose) of the interval length, then return a `'1'`, else `'0'`. The 0th index is always true aslong as 0 < n <= 12 at least..

Comment: @Kevin when cheking if the index is multiple of the interval length, why do you use % instead of / ?

Comment: Because that's the best way I know to do it :) I guess you could check if a multiple is exact, but it wouldn't work for the fractional rollover that I'm kind of relying on in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The average length of each interval is `12/N` (in mathematical terms, not integer division). To enforce the differ-by-one rule, the only options are `ceil(12/N)` ("long") and `floor(12/N)` ("short"). The number of each required is `12 % N` and `N - (12 % N)`. i.e. in Python

```
def allocate_intervals(N):
    short = 12 // N # integer division
    long = short + 1

    # lists of [1,0, ..., 0] lists
    short_intervals = [[1] + [0] * (short - 1)] * (N - (12 % N))
    long_intervals =  [[1] + [0] * (long - 1)] * (12 % N)

    # concatenate to get [1, 0, ..., 1, 0, ...]
    return sum(short_intervals + long_intervals, [])
```

The above code creates the appropriate number of each interval and then concatenates.

(This method is fully general, one can replace the `12`s by any positive integer.)

---

A slightly different implementation of the above in C/C++ etc.

```c
// array is [0, 0, ..., 0] with 12 elements. It is modified in-place.
void allocate_intervals(int N, int array[12]) {
   // length of each interval
   int len_short = 12 / N, len_long = len_short + 1;

   // number of each interval
   int num_long = 12 % N, num_short = N - num_long;

   int step = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < num_long; i++) {
      array[step] = 1;
      step += len_long;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < num_short; i++) {
      array[step] = 1;
      step += len_short;
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps rewrite your code in pseudo-code or C++ or even comment all steps you do here, because I have very hard time understanding this code as I don't really know python. Thank you a lot anyway.

Comment: whats the difference between short and long intervals ?

Comment: One is longer than the other.

Comment: could you explain how do you know the number of these intervals length and numbers of both intervals required ?

Comment: could you please explain ? I unaccepted your answer for you to notice, I will accept it as soon as you respond, even if you won't bother explaining.

Comment: There's no other choice for the lengths (any other choice doesn't satisfy the differ-by-one requirement). The number comes if you regard the long intervals as a short one, plus a little bit extra, so you have `N` "short" intervals and then some extra that you need to put in to make sure that it makes it to 12. The amount extra is `12 % N` (the remainder after dividing 12 by `N`). Each long interval only gives you 1 more distance, so you need `12 % N` long intervals to add up to 12. (Total length if you only had short intervals is `N * len_short`, so you must add `12 % N` to get to 12.)

Comment: thank you for answering, however I still have hard time understanding your code. Another question why do you first go over array with long interval and only then with short ? How do you know that the second loop is going to increment array's elements correctly after the first loop ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really make it any clearer, you might have to experiment by hand (with say 5 instead of 12, and use N=1,...,5.) to try to get a feel for how it works. (You could also print the array at each step of the loops to see how it fills the array.)

Comment: To answer your other questions, the way I've implemented it is the neatest way I could find. It uses the `step` variable to indicate which element it is incrementing (notice that `step` is no reset between the loops).

Comment: only now I noticed that your algorithm doesn't work with not even numbers, for example with 7. it gives 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 when it should actually give me 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 or something similiar

Comment: Did you copy-paste it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is `int n = 12 / N` gives the period.

**Updated code.** 
This will work for all cases from 1 to 12. Cases beyond 6 use symmetry property to avoid continuous 1's

```
public int[] Splitter(int N, int max) // max = 12 for above problem.
{
    if (max < 1 || N < 1 || N > max)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    if (N != max && N > max / 2)
    {
        return Splitter(max - N, max).Select(s => s == 1 ? 0 : 1).ToArray();
    }

    int[] a = new int[max];
    int n = max / N;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        if (i % n == 0 && count < N)
        {
            a[i] = 1;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            a[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

**old code:**

```
int n = 12 / N;
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
  if (i % n == 0)
  {
    a[i] = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    a[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The lengths of the intervals can differ by more than 1.

Comment: @dbaupp - Seems to me like it works.  Do you have an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @Ankush - You just need to modify this to stop adding 1's after N is reached.

Comment: @mbeckish, still doesn't work. The last interval is too long.

Comment: @Ankush - Nevermind.  That would fix it for N==5, but not N > 6.

Comment: @mbeckish updated the code. this uses symmetry for remaining cases.

Comment: @dbaupp thanks for pointing out those cases. updated the code to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

If all what are you having is an array of 12 elements, then you can use brute-force recursive backtracking:

```
Arr = [ ] // holds best solution
tempArr = [ ] // temproray

function rec( i, n )
     if n == 0
        return
     if i == Arr.length
        checkBest(Arr, tempArr) // copies tempArr to Arr if it is better solution
        return
     tempArr[i] = 1
     rec(i + 1, n - 1)
     tempArr[i] = 0
     rec(i + 1, n)
```

Usage: rec(0, 1234)

Answer (score 0):

```
def alloc(N, length=12):

    result = zeros(length) # preinitialise an array with zeros

    short_gap = length // N # where // is integer division
    long_gap = short_gap + 1

    change_over_index = (N - (length % N)) * (length // N)

    result[0:change_over_index:short_gap] = 1
    result[change_over_index:length:long_gap] = 1
    # above two lines of code is called slicing. arr[x:y:z] = 1 means:
    # set all indexes from x to y by increments of z to be 1... eg.
    # for (int i = x; i < y; i += z) arr[i] = 1;

    return result
```